# Is there a circular dependency between class loader and class garbage collection?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, garbage-collection

I am reading about GC and in particular I read [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/class-loader-issues/) and [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7), and I am getting an impression that there is a circular dependency between the GC of classes and class loaders because classes hold a reference to class loaders which loaded them and class loaders hold a reference to all the classes that loaded them.

Also, if a class holds reference to a class loader and vice-versa, then I wonder how they can ever get GC'ed-of course, unless the JVM is shutdown or the application is unloaded.

Could a JVM expert please confirm or correct my understanding? Any extra information or explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Circular chains of reference don't inhibit GC. The class won't be collected until the classloader is, which may be never in the case of the system class loader. For application-created classloaders, the application would have to release all references to them.

Comment: As soon as you see “PermGen” in an article, you can stop reading or should only continue reading with great care. The “PermGen” does not exist anymore, since Java 8, in other words, since almost a decade.